# Passing json block as env vars to spring config server application.yml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

pretty new to spring, trying to deploy a spring config server with external parameters on linux.
using spring initializer to setup and deploy the server
have created a bootstrap.yml file

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local,development,production
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/solivaf/config-properties-foo
          repos: ${repo}
```

So here im trying to set values for the variable "repo" using env vars.
The env var im trying to set is

```
export repo='{ "appFoo":{"pattern":"app-foo", "uri":"https://github.com/solivaf/config-properties-bar"} }'
```

This fails  with the error -

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.repos' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJG
itEnvironmentProperties$PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentProperties>:

    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.cloud.config.server.envir
onment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties$PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentProperties>]
```

However if i manually set this value inn the bootstrap.yml file, it seems to be working.
So it seems i'm having issues only if i try and pass this value as an env var.
Not sure if this is the right way of passing variables 
Appreciate your help on this

Thanks,